# How to best save data which overlaps?

Tags: javascript, json, xml, database, save

Say I have a text which is comprised of multiple chapters, which are comprised of multiple paragraphs, which are comprised of multiple sentences. In a JSON, I would maybe save this as follows:

```
// Pseudo Code
    chapter {
     paragraphs {
      sentences {
      }
     }
    }
```

However, let's introduce another unit which needs to be saved / kept track of, and let's call it a 'section'. A section also holds sentences and can extend over multiple paragraphs, but is completely independent of the paragraphs, i.e. it will not always cleanly wrap up whole paragraphs, but sometimes just once sentence of a paragraph, at other times extend over 1 1/2 paragraphs.

I do not know where and how to save this -either in JSON or in XML. I also would like to not repeat myself and save this information somewhere else, as it would make sense for my application to have it all in one place.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not use back end with database?

Answer (score 0):

Not easy solution, but that can work...

Smaller common denominator is *sentences*, I will put an non mandatory attribute on each sentence with a reference (or not) to a *section*.

```
chapter : [
  1 : {                                // Chapter 1
    paragraphs : [
      1 : {                            // Paragraph 1.1
        sentences : [
          1 : {
            text : 'sentence 1',
            section : ''
          },
          2 : {
            text : 'sentence 2',
            section : 'section 1'
          }
        ]
     }, 
     2 : {                              // Paragraph 1.2
       sentences : [
          1 : {
            text : 'sentence 3',
            section : ''
          },
          2 : {
            text : 'sentence 4',
            section : 'section 1'
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
  2 : {                                // Chapter 2
    paragraphs : [
      1 : {                            // Paragraph 2.1
        sentences : [
          1 : {
            text : 'sentence 5',
            section : 'section 1'
          },
      }
    ]
]
```

Here, *section 1* will group sentence 2 (chapter 1 / paragraph 1), sentence 4 (chapter 1 / paragraph 2) and sentence 5 (chapter 2 / paragraph 1)

Answer (score 0):

You need to be aware that a lot of work has been done over the years in the markup community on the modelling of overlapping hierarchies. There's an overview in Wikipedia:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overlapping_markup

which is probably a good place to start your reading.

There is also work from the data processing community: Michael Jackson's JSD/JSP methods from the 1970s include a significant amount of material on transforming one hierarchy into another when there is a "boundary conflict" (i.e. neither hierarchy maps directly onto the other). The (unsuccessful) ISO ODA (office document architecture) standards from the 1980s were particularly concerned with the relationship of the logical structure of a document (chapters, sections, paragraphs) with the paginated representation (page-sets, pages, columns, blocks) which is one special case of two overlapping hierarchies; and of course a lot of the thinking behind XSLT was concerned with the transformations needed to get from the logical hierarchy of a document to its paginated representation.

So before you re-invent the wheel, take a look at how others have tackled the problem.